# Publishing app on Heroku using node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, heroku

I have a couple of questions about an app that I am making and publishing on Heroku. I've made a simple HTML/JS game and I want to implement some server side scripts. I have some experience with node and socket.io but I don't know how they work on a Heroku platform. The game is an asynchronous trivia game.

I have the following questions:

1) I want to have many server side functions, how will I call a specific function and pass specific parameters from client side, and vice versa?

Example: Client calls function on server that player 1 finished move (with some answer), I process that info in database and want to then call client side function of player 2 that he is on move.

2) Where should I put server side scripts when I'm deploying?

3) What changes do I need to make in package.json when I want to implement node and what changes should I make for socket.io?

I know that those are some trivial stuff but I never did something like this before and other documentations are unclear, too complicated for stuff like this, etc... I would really appreciate help.

Comment: You can also host your app on xervo.com  it provides best hosting for node.js

Comment: @RohitKumar Thank you on your suggestion but I like Heroku because platform handles all other stuff about publishing app on Facebook.

Comment: Can anyone help me? Bump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How will I call a specific function and pass specific parameters from
>      client side, and vice versa?

- You could develop an API. That way you can make ajax calls from your client-side(front-end) to your API(back-end). It’s very simple with express. Follow [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) tutorial and you will get there .
- With an API developed, it’ll be pretty easy for you to handle database queries, scalability and more.

> 2. Where should I put server side scripts when I'm deploying?

- Since you will have an API, your “functions” will be at urls “http://api.example.com/get-players” that you will call using ajax calls.

> 3) What changes do I need to make in package.json when I want to
>   implement node and what changes do I make for socket.io?

- I’ve never developed a service using socket.io. I think you’d only have to add the name of the package. Below, are videos to help you deploy the apps to [heroku](http://heroku.com)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUqB77UO4E0
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZNFox2CvBk

Comment: Thank you my friend! Answer on my first question is BINGO!